# Joining Multiple Dataframes with and conditions in Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to Implement beolw sql join condition using Pyspark dataframe.

```
    select *
    FROM tableA A, tablec C, tableB  B
    A.sno = C.sno AND A.sno = B.sno AND 
    A.sdt = C.sdt AND A.sdt = B.sdt 
    AND A.sid = C.sid AND A.sid = B.sid
```

I have tried below code(df_A0,df_C0,df_B0 are 3 different dataframes)

```
    join_data = df_A0.join(df_C0, (df_A0.sno===df_C0.sno).join(df_B0, (df_A0.sno===df_B0.sno)) & \
    (df_A0.sdt === df_C0.sdt) & (df_A0.sdt === df_B0.sdt) & (df_A0.sid === df_C0.sid) & \
     df_A0.sid = df_B0.sid,how='inner'))
```

but  when i executing this its showing invalid syntax error.

Can someone please guide me how should write it in pyspark dataframes.

Comment: There is no triple equal in python `===`. Check your parenthesis, they do not open/close properly.  `invalid syntax error` means simply you wrote bad python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below like below,

```
join_data = df_A0.alias("df_A0").join(df_C0.alias("df_C0"), (df_A0.sno == df_C0.sno) & (df_A0.sdt == df_C0.sdt) & (df_A0.sid == df_C0.sid),"inner")\
    .join(df_B0.alias("df_B0"), (df_A0.sno == df_B0.sno) & (df_A0.sdt == df_B0.sdt) & (df_A0.sid == df_B0.sid), "inner")
```

More on Spark-SQL click on [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/index.html).